# Created desktop shortcut in Elementary Linux, does not appear in list of applications

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, desktop, database

After a couple of hours of tinkering I have Oracle SQL Developer installed on ElementaryOS (based off Ubuntu) and created a desktop shortcut `Oracle SQL developer.desktop` in `/usr/share/applicatons`

Only thing is, when I open up the applications menu from the GUI it doesn't appear.

Code from the .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Oracle SQL Developer
Icon=/sqldeveloper/icon.png
Exec=sqldeveloper
```

Output from ls -l /usr/share/applicatons/Oracle SQL developer.desktop

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 120 Aug 31 13:48 /usr/share/applications/Oracle SQL Developer.desktop
```

All other .desktop files are also -rw-r--r--

As a workaround I can open SQL Developer from terminal by running `sqldeveloper` but I'd like to use the shortcut I created. Any ideas what to do to get this to appear in the applications menu?

Cheers

Comment: EDIT: copied to dock at the bottom of the screen from the folder, but doesn't appear in applications list

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the contents of the `.desktop` file and also the output of `ls -l /usr/share/applicatons/Oracle\ SQL\ developer.desktop` please?

Comment: I can confirm that the exact same setup you describe causes a menu item to appear on my machine (Cinnamon environment). ElemntaryOS uses [pantheon](http://elementaryos.org/journal/meet-me-pantheon) do you know that the menu works in a similar way? Does it work if you use a different name (preferably one with no spaces)? Try editing one of the other .desktop files, does that change what appears in the menu?

Comment: I checked a few of the others, and realised I was missing the category, highlighted in red in Scratch's syntax highlighting.

I put it under 'Categories=Development' and it appeared in the menu.

Comment: I've not got enough rep points to answer my own question :(

Comment: What? It should require [no reputation](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/) to answer a question, are you sure?

Comment: Ah, oops. I can't answer it yet. Have to wait another 4 hours until I mark it as answered. cheers

Comment: You should still be able to post the answer, you need to wait for four hours _after posting an answer_ in order to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked a few of the other .desktop files, and realised I was missing the category, highlighted in red in Scratch's syntax highlighting.

I put it under

```
Categories=Development
```

and it appeared.

As a note, you can put multiple categories for one item, but only the ones that highlight in red in (Scratch, I don't know about Gedit) will appear in the menu in Elementary.

Comment: You're missing a `;`

desktop-entry-validate returns _error: value "Development" for string list key "Categories" in group "Desktop Entry" does not have a semicolon (';') as trailing character_